# Detect Jquery blur event on window with 100width and height iframe in it?

Tags: iframe, detect, onblur

My site is site with 100% iframe in it.
In iframe are opening different external links.
Some pages opened in Iframe have links wich
open in new window(outside iframe).

I want to alert users that they are leaving my domain eg. 
leaving iframe.

I tried a lot off examples found here for window.blur event.
But because focus is constantly on iframe(page in iframe) nothing
works for me.

I only want to detect when new window from external link in iframe happened
and do some stuff.

I'm new in this things , so please understand me.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/fisitotehi/edit?html,js,output

> I want to alert users that they are leaving my domain eg. leaving
>   iframe.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Comment: Thank you for response but it works only on window close not on new tab opend.